# iPhone 3GS Contacts 'Sometimes' Won't Sync Back to Exchange

Tags: iphone, exchange, contacts

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this so just thought I'd find out if it's a known issue or if it's just happening to me. since I first got my 3GS, I've had it synced with Micorsoft Exchange (initially 2003, now 2008).

If I go into my contacts on the phone and add a new contact it immediately syncs back at my Exchange server and vice versa. However, sometimes if I add a contact via one of the 'quick links' (Like if I get a text from someone not already in my Contacts on the phone, then use the facility to create a contact for this number), while the contact is visible on the iPhone, it 'never' makes it to the Exchange server.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: are you saving the contacts you create on the SIM card or on the phone's memory?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also; the solution is pretty simple.  On your iPhone, go to "Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars" and scroll down to the Contacts section.  Change the "Default Account" setting from "On My iPhone" to your Exchange server.  This will ensure that contacts created from an e-mail or a text message are synced to Exchange.

Comment: I don't have a 'Default Account' setting under Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Contacts. I just have a 'Sort Order', 'Display Order' and 'Import SIM Contacts' options there. I'm on iOS 4.01 on an iPhone 4 if that helps?

Comment: A method to enable the "Default Account" option from http://goo.gl/1o9Lm
1) In iTunes, on the Info tab for your iPhone, check the box next to "Sync Address Book contacts" (using a Mac—PC may be different)
WARNING:  If you don't use the Address Book on your computer, continue.  If you do use your Address Book, all of those contacts will probably be added to your iPhone in addition to whatever is already there.  If you are ok with this, continue.
2) Sync iTunes with your iPhone
3) "Default Account" should now appear under contact settings.
4) Uncheck "Sync Address Book contacts" in iTunes.

Comment: This solution was specific to Google Sync, but I don't see any reason for it not to work for any Exchange account.